# No coge los parametros get de la url

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

hace poco hice un pequeño refactor de mi aplicación y han dejado de funcionarme las tablas paginadas y creo que es porque no esta cogiendo la páginación que se pasa por parámetros GET en la url.

Antes del refactor tenía una clase index.php que incluía todo el html junto con php, pero para optimizar y no duplicar código, empece a separar lo que sería, el menu de navegación, el navbar superior, y el contenido en diferentes ficheros .php, de tal forma que al entrar en una web utilizando este código me carga la página entera:

```
    $(function () {
        $.get("../navbar.php", function (data) {
          $("#navbar-menu").append(data);
        });
        $.get("../menu.php", function (data) {
          $("#sidebar-wrapper").append(data);
        });
        $.get("./content.php", function (data) {
          $("#divPersonal").append(data);
        });
    });
```

Al entrar por ejemplo en una de estas páginas donde tengo una tabla con páginación y enlaces tipo:

```
http://localhost/app/modules/users/index.php?pagina=2
```

Cuando recarga el index.php y este carga con javascript el "content.php" donde tengo la llamada en php de "getUsers()", esta debería coger la URL y el parámetro "pagina" pero no lo esta haciendo, y parece que es debido a la forma que en que se esta montando mi index.php. No consigo encontrar una solución óptima para resolver este problema. Yo cojo los parámetros directamente al llamar a la función con un if:

```
if (empty($_GET['pagina'])) {
  $inicioPagina = 0;
  $paginaActual = 1; // Valor que varia y habrá que pasarlo por parámetro
} else {
  $paginaActual = $_GET["pagina"];
  $inicioPagina = ($paginaActual - 1) * $TAMANO_PAGINA;
}
```

Si alguien me puede ayudar, gracias y un saludo.

Comment: ¿Cómo se sabe en el browser cuál es la página actual?

Comment: por la url como he indicado en la pregunta, y si te fijas en el código php, hace la comprobación de que si en la url (parámetro "página") no esta vacia, pues coje el valor de la página actual en la que se encuentre, de lo contrario, si no existe, es que esta en la primera página.